# Beginner help installing Sophos antivirus package on elementary os Loki

Tags: release-loki, software-installation, thirdpartyapps

I've downloaded the free Sophos antivirus package for Linux (is this a good antivirus for eOS Loki?). However, I'm still a beginner and I don't know how to install it.

I extracted the package in the Downloads folder:

```
/home/anna/Downloads/sav-linux-free-9.tgz
```

The extracted files are:

```
install.sh
sav.tar
talpa.tar
uncdownload.tar
```

I don't know what to do next. I tried following the Sophos online instructions for installing on a standalone, but I didn't know how to copy the package to a temporary folder and when I enter the install command in root, it says it can't locate the package:

> Download the relevant tarball for your platform and copy it to a
>   temporary directory. For example: `/tmp`
>
> Change to the temporary directory and untar the tarball. For example:
>
> ```
> cd /tmp
> tar -xzvf tarball
> Run the install script:
> ./sophos-av/install.sh
> ```
>
> Follow the on-screen instructions to complete installation.

There is no support for home linux users from Sophos. Can anyone in this community help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the sav-linux-free-9.tgz file, it will be in the Downloads folder.

Yes, like you said, the instructions say to copy it to a temporary directory.

**1)** Create the directory (I use /opt): `sudo mkdir /opt/sophos`

**2)** From your downloads folder, extract the file into the newly created folder:

```
sudo tar -xzvf sav-linux-free-9.tgz -C /opt/sophos
```

**3)** Change to the folder: `cd /opt/sophos`

**4)** Install Sophos: `sudo ./sophos-av/install.sh`

**5)** For most of the prompts, you can select the default. But when prompted for Free or Supported, choose Free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do most of mine in the file manager GUI, but basically the same:

Create a directory Sophos in the Downloads folder

Download the .tgz file into the folder

Right click on the downloaded .tgz file and extract it.

Go into the terminal and navigate to the extracted folder:

cd Downloads/Sophos/sophos-av

Install:

sudo sh ./install.sh

Follow the prompts and answer where required.  I think picking the free version is not a default so watch out for that.

When you are finished run:

sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savupdate

Wait for it to finish.

It's a good anti-virus but I found it created a little lag in my system so I turn off the service when I am not scanning.